# How to create a Function2 instance using lambdas in Java?

Tags: lambda, java-8

I am trying to implement a lambda Function2 in Java:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> reducedCounts = counts.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call(final Integer value0, final Integer value1) {
        return Integer.valueOf(value0.intValue() + value1.intValue());
    }
});
```

The above is a sample, but how to change it to a lamb8 format? I wanna define as a separate function

```
Function2<...> f2 = LAMBDA;
counts.reduceByKey(f2);
```

Comment: `counts.reduceByKey( (x,y) -> x + y)`

Answer (score 3):

You can go for a method reference which is the easiest option in this case:

```
Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer> f2 = Integer::sum;
counts.reduceByKey(f2)
```

which is equal to:

```
Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer> f2 = (i1, i1) -> i1 + i2;
counts.reduceByKey(f2)
```

---

Also, such simplification is possible because you perform a lot of unnecessary boxing/unboxing in order to calculate the sum of two integers.

Comment: @Luckylukee I believe this is exactly what you are looking for :)

Comment: Very clean. I was about to misstep by writing a lambda. Must remember method references!!

Answer (score 2):

Since `Function2` is a functional interface, you can implement it with a simple lambda expression:

```
Function2<Integer,Integer,Integer> plus = (x,y)->Integer.valueOf(x.intValue()+y.intValue());
```

If your logic is more than a simple expression, you can use a block:

```
Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer> plus = (x, y) -> {
   // do stuff
   return Integer.valueOf(x.intValue()+y.intValue());
};
```

In case of a simple integer addition, you can take advantage of auto-unboxing and write this more simply as:

```
Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer> plus = (x, y) -> x + y;
```

You can also take advantage of `sum` method in `Integer` class to use a method reference:

```
Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer> plus = Integer::sum;
```

Comment: any advice on this , how to handle this UDF issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas